Facebook Graph API Beiträge Poste?
I'm desperately trying to post a post with an image and an image URL via the Facebook Graph API. No matter what I do, I always get error messages.
Does anyone here have any sample code or ideas on how to implement this with Python? I would be very grateful for constructive answers!
import requests
from io import BytesIO

def post_facebook_photo(message, image_url):
    access_token = 'DEIN_ACCESS_TOKEN'
    feed_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/me/feed"
    
    try:
      
        image_response = requests.get(image_url)
        image_response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Fehler beim Herunterladen des Bildes: {e}")
        return

    image_file = BytesIO(image_response.content)
    
  
    photo_upload_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/me/photos"
    photo_data = {'access_token': access_token}
    photo_files = {'file': ('image.jpg', image_file, 'image/jpeg')}
    
    photo_response = requests.post(photo_upload_url, data=photo_data, files=photo_files)
    photo_response_data = photo_response.json()

    if 'id' in photo_response_data:
        photo_id = photo_response_data['id']
        post_data = {
            'message': message,
            'attached_media': [{'media_fbid': photo_id}],
            'access_token': access_token
        }
        
        post_response = requests.post(feed_url, json=post_data)
        return post_response.json()
    else:
        return photo_response_data

response = post_facebook_photo("Hier ist ein neues Bild!", "IMAGE-URL")
print(response)

